# Issues with ng serve Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install

I have a problem with the installation of an existing angular application.

I'm trying to launch the application with the `ng serve` command, and this error is occurring:
`The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`.

I've installed all the packages provided in the `package.json` file with the `npm install` command, I know they are a bit outdated, but they are still supposed to work.

These are all the dev dependencies:

```
"card"                             : "^1.2",
"del"                              : "latest",
"gulp"                             : "latest",
"gulp-autoprefixer"                : "latest",
"gulp-concat"                      : "latest",
"gulp-cssnano"                     : "2.x",
"gulp-eslint"                      : "latest",
"gulp-html5-lint"                  : "latest",
"gulp-htmlmin"                     : "2.x",
"gulp-imagemin"                    : "latest",
"gulp-inline-source"               : "latest",
"gulp-notify"                      : "latest",
"gulp-plumber"                     : "latest",
"gulp-rev-all"                     : "latest",
"gulp-sass"                        : "latest",
"gulp-scss-lint"                   : "latest",
"gulp-sourcemaps"                  : "2.0.0-alpha",
"gulp-svg-sprite"                  : "latest",
"gulp-tslint"                      : "4.x",
"gulp-typescript"                  : "2.x",
"gulp-uglify"                      : "latest",
"gulp-util"                        : "latest",
"merge-stream"                     : "latest",
"tslint"                           : "3.x",
"browser-sync"                     : "2.x",
"connect-history-api-fallback"     : "latest",
"typescript"                       : "1.x",
"typings"                          : "^0.8.1",
"svg4everybody"                    : "2.x",
"jquery"                           : "2.x",
"jasmine"                          : "2.x",
"semantic-ui"                      : "2.x",
"@angular/common"                  : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler"                : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli"            : "^2.0.x",
"@angular/core"                    : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http"                    : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser"        : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router"                  : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated"       : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade"                 : "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/cli"                     : "1.4.8",
"systemjs"                         : "0.19.27",
"es6-shim"                         : "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata"                 : "^0.1.3",
"rxjs"                             : "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js"                          : "^0.6.12",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api"       : "0.0.7"
```

Anyone has an idea on how to resolve this? I'm struggling on this because I'm pretty new to Angular, any suggestion is accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried updating the CLI?

Comment: Since you are using an old Angular 2 version, you can't use a newer Angular CLI with it. Uninstall whatever version of Angular CLI you have and install Angular CLI beta 28 and see if ng serve works.

If memory serves me well, it should be something like this:
 npm i angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3 -g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with this `npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3` (installing that version of cli globally)

Answer (score 0):

for enable angular cli commands, you must install it in global area of node by this command

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```